# Google Maps - Drag & drop markers and draw routes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to implement an interface like below with jQuery/JS and Laravel PHP framework. Could anyone help me to figure out the following questions I have?

[image: easyvan]

1. How to make the markers draggable and on marker release get the
   lat/lon?
2. How can I show the real path between point 1 & 2 (like the blue line. when I change the marker a new line will be drawn based on the shortest distance)?
3. If there are multiple markers connecting to each others like below, how can I get the optimise route?

For markers are connecting to each others.
[image: 4 markers]

This is the optimise route to visit all 4 markers (shortest path to visit)
[image: optimise]

4. Is there an open source project similar to this? (like jQuery calendar)

If you know any resources/plugins related to achieving something like this please comment below.

Comment: Directions Example : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Draggable markers on Google Map - search for "Make a marker draggable":
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

Planning route from point A to point B based on road map. You can use Directions API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

Comment: Thanks Maksym, Is there a way to show the best optimise route from multiple A, B, C points in Google maps?

Comment: Google does it for use. Look at departure_time and traffic_model . If departure_time is close to current time, it may optimize route based on actual traffic conditions. It similar to what you get while using Google Maps for navigation of phone. I've seen cases when with same start and end points different route was computed due to heavy traffic